# What is the difference between heap and swap memory?

Tags: linux, cassandra

What is the difference between heap and swap memory in Ubuntu/Any OS? How does this affect in choosing Cassandra?

Comment: Did you try googling your question title? There is literally tons of information right there at your fingertips

Comment: Both terms ("heap memory" and "swap memory") have nothing to do with each other. Why do you ask for a "difference" between both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heap memory is what the jvm uses, swap is what OS uses to push things not used often onto disk and save memory. Its **very** recommended to disable swap on C* hosts, as the old gen objects in jvm may get pushed onto disk, and when a GC occurs and it gets touched it will be very slow. If it can C* will pin its memory to prevent itself from being swapped, but you should disable it anyway.